# Octokit returning one pull request rather than all issues

Tags: node.js, github-api, octokit

I wish to retrieve all issues from a GitHub repository in my Node.js application. I've used octokit to do this. From the documentation I gather I must use `repo.getIssueEvents()` but this just returns the 1st pull request which is not what I expected.

I've tried Googling this but keep coming across the same documentation that I've already used. Waht am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var GitHubApi = require('octokit');
retrieveIssues: function(owner, repoName) {

  var gh = GitHubApi.new({  
  username: "user",
  password: "password"
  });


  var repo = gh.getRepo(owner, repoName);

  repo.getIssueEvents()
    .then(function(events) {console.log(events)})

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to [this octokit project](https://github.com/philschatz/octokit.js), it seems it doesn't expose Github API to [get issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) but only [issue events](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#list-events-for-a-repository) for a specific repository.

[Here](https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/), Github recommends using [octokit/rest](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js) for [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)

```
npm install @octokit/rest
```

To get all issues (issues & pull request in all state) it would be :

```
const octokit = require('@octokit/rest')()

async function paginate(method) {
    let response = await method({
        owner: "google",
        repo: "gson",
        state: "all",
        per_page: 100
    })
    let {
        data
    } = response
    var count = 0;
    while (octokit.hasNextPage(response)) {
        count++;
        console.log(`${count} request`);
        response = await octokit.getNextPage(response)
        data = data.concat(response.data)
    }
    return data
}

paginate(octokit.issues.getForRepo)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Check [issues.getForRepo](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#api-Issues-getForRepo)

If you don't want pull requests but only issues you could also perform a search request like this :

```
const octokit = require('@octokit/rest')()

octokit.authenticate({
    type: 'oauth',
    token: 'YOUR_TOKEN'
});

async function paginate(method) {
    let response = await method({
        q: "repo:google/gson is:issue",
        per_page: 100
    })
    let data = response.data.items;
    var count = 0;
    while (octokit.hasNextPage(response)) {
        count++;
        console.log(`request n°${count}`);
        response = await octokit.getNextPage(response);
        data = data.concat(response.data.items);
    }
    return data
}

paginate(octokit.search.issues)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(`retrieved ${data.length} issues`);
    })
```

But note that only the first 1000 issues are returned in search requests

Comment: I realised I was using the wrong package but thats as far as I had got. thanks for your explanation. Its been very helpful.